# Start an activity from notification depending on application status

Tags: android, navigation, android-notifications

I'm trying to setup FirebaseMessagingService and am struggling with navigation logic.

When user taps on a notification an activity which is `not the main` one should be started.

I know that it is possible to start an activity either by its own like this

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
```

or with a backstack like this

```
val pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
    addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
    getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
}
```

The problem with the first variant is that if the `application is not running` then when user closes the intent activity the entire app is closed because there is no backstack behind it.

The problem with the second variant is that if the `app is running` and the `current activity is not the parent of the intent` activity then when the user closes the intent activity he can't get back to the previous one because it got replaced by the new backstack.

What I need is: when the user closes the intent actvity then start the main one but only if there is no backstack available.

Any idea please how to solve this navigation issue?

Answer (score 0):

Posting a workaround solution for my own question.

Set a flag when starting MainActivity and check for it when finishing the notification activity.

In the MainActivity

```
companion object {
    var started: Boolean = false
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    started = true
```

In the Notification activity

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (!MainActivity.started)
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```